# Problem with Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a List of integers

```
 List<int> LI = new List<int>();
```

i wants check whether a particular number exists in the list.if exists do a database updation else do a database insert

```
foreach (int IT in LI)
        {

        }
```

can i do this inside the foreach loop or if not possible how to achieve this?????

Comment: You might also want to look into better names then LI for you variables such as updateList

Comment: Please don't use ALL-CAPS for local variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
if(LI.Contains(someIntValue))
{
  // do database update
}
```

Which will search every element in the list and compare it to `someIntValue`, and return true once an element that matches is found, or false if no element matches.

Now, this is inefficient because the time to search a list is linear. If you are constantly searching your list you should probably be storing your integers in a collection that is better suited for searching such as `Dictionary` or `HashSet` which both have constant time

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alan.My List is not a long one.it can contain 20-25 elements so what's the collection i should use and what is the efficiency of Dictionary or HashSet over List

Comment: +1 for mentioning better suiting data structures for this problem. [Here](http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time) you'll find a comparison between the lookup time of a `Dictionary` and the one of a `List`

Comment: @chamara: If you're using .NET 3.5 or newer then use HashSet, as it is specific to searching. Dictionary is a more appropriate collection for to associating keys with values. If you're using .Net 3.0 or older, use Dictonary.

Comment: @Giu: Interesting link, but it assumes `int`.  A search on `string` is likely to have a somewhat different break-even point.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void InsertUpdateNumber(int i){

    if(LI.Any(li => li == i))
        //do update
    else
        //do insert

}
```

Comment: a bit for this scenario but can be extended to complex scenarios with the same logic, like for ex: check for existence of an employee and department combination in a list of employee Information data